# QGIS unexpectedly crashing

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, zoom, download

I'm trying to make a full map of Staten island.  The first picture shows all the vector layers I am using with out a problem.  Once I turn on Open Street Maps layer, QGIS takes a while to render as I zoom in and out and then most of the time just crashes (as seen in picture 2).  How can I fix this so I can easily zoom in and out without the QGIS taking forever to render it and then crash? I've tried fresh installing the updated QGIS but that didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're using the OpenLayers plugin (which has some issues), perhaps you can try the OSM layers from the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead?

Comment: I am using the Open Layers plugin... Like you suggested, I am trying the OSM layer from QuickMapServices and while it is still having rendering issues, at least its not crashing!! (yet) .. thank you!

Comment: Most welcome! Hopefully it won't crash your QGIS ;)

Comment: @Joseph perhaps you could convert your comment to an answer